# Pulling a value on a known line in the HTML source into an Excel spreadsheet

Tags: html, vba, excel

I have a series of order numbers, and I want to add their status into an Excel spreadsheet, which will update as that status changes.

I have set up the spreadsheet, and I have created a formula that adds hyperlinks to the orders on my site in a separate column, so I have a correct URL for every instance. These hyperlinks lead to an overview page for the particular order, on which page there is an order status.  Unfortunately the status isn't a separate HTML table, so I can't just use the web query tool.  I know where that status can be found within the source code, and that location remains constant across all orders.  I'm looking for a way to pull in this data that would allow it to refresh hourly, and allow me to easily repeat the process for several hundred orders.

Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: No HTML, no URL, no code.....Not [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Selenium-vba](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fp%2Fselenium-vba%2F&ei=QbRuVYH9Ksn9UPfwgvgH&usg=AFQjCNGdbIx_-fCzI3G0sM_YAiAMtb_IdQ&sig2=_lAT4FdhnPwn0SX199I9yg) which is the VBA implementation of Selenium.

Selenium allows you perfom automated tests in various languages (mainly Java) and has a developing tool for Firefox.

There are currently some problems with selenium-vba and Firefox (just to aviod that you spend to much time with this current issue) but you can run the test/routines also with Chrome.